# Loading ECMA script API / Access sharepoint from web site hosted externally from sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I'm developing a web application externally from sharepoint online 2010. As part of the application I would like to allow users to access documents from a document library. Ideally users would click on an option, this would query the library for documents, and return a JSON object for each object satisfying the query for display as links in a webpage.

I've been looking for a way to do this in a website hosted externally from sharepoint 2010, but I have been unable to find resources describing how to load the ECMA script API (is there a CDN?) and connect to a sharepoint site. Does anyone know where I can find this information?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are many resources to help you get started. MS is moving towards using the Client Side Object Model to do all kinds of interfaces with SharePoint. So you are asking the right question. Here are 3 links that should help you identify the basics for writing against the CSOM. The other benefit of these 3 links is that they should get you going with the terms to use for searches.

http://www.infoq.com/articles/swanson-moss-web-services

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/hh372944(v=office.14).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/04/20/uploading-files-using-the-rest-api-and-client-side-techniques.aspx